# Why does this goroutine behave like it's call by reference?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to learn the basics of Go and I'm a bit confused about the difference between call by value and call by reference in a code snippet I tested.

I tried to solve a [coding game puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/tictactoe) in which a solution for a tic-tac-toe field is to be calculated.

---

#### The code I'm using

Because I'm learning Go, I wanted to use a goroutine to test every field of the tic-tac-toe board, check whether this field is the solution and then put a pointer to this field in a channel for the main method to have the result. The code I used looks like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

var player int = int('O')
var opponent int = int('X')
var empty int = int('.')

type board struct {
    fields [][]int
}

func main() {
    lines := [3]string {"OO.", "...", "..."}

    var b board
    b.fillBoard(lines)
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "input board:")
    b.printBoard(true)

    resultChannel := make(chan *board)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            go tryField(b, [2]int{i, j}, resultChannel) // goroutine call that isn't working as expected
        }
    }

    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "\nresult:")
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        resultBoard := <- resultChannel
        if (resultBoard != nil) {
            resultBoard.printBoard(false)
            return
        }
    }
    
    // fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Debug messages...")
    fmt.Println("false")// Write answer to stdout
}

func tryField(b board, field [2]int, result chan *board) {
    b.printBoard(true)
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "add O to field: ", field)
    fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "\n")
    if (b.fields[field[0]][field[1]] != empty) {
        result <- nil
    }

    b.fields[field[0]][field[1]] = player
    if (b.isWon()) {
        result <- &b
    } else {
        result <- nil
    }
}


func (b *board) fillBoard(lines [3]string) {
    b.fields = make([][]int, 3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        b.fields[i] = make([]int, 3)
    }

    for i, line := range lines {
        for j, char := range line {
            b.fields[i][j] = int(char)
        }
    }
}

func (b *board) printBoard(debug bool) {
    var stream *os.File
    if (debug) {
        stream = os.Stderr
    } else {
        stream = os.Stdout
    }
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            fmt.Fprint(stream, string(b.fields[i][j]))
        }
        fmt.Fprint(stream, "\n")
    }
}

func (b *board) isWon() bool {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        rowFull := true
        colFull := true
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            rowFull = rowFull && b.fields[i][j] == player
            colFull = rowFull && b.fields[j][i] == player
        }
        if (rowFull || colFull) {
            return true
        }
    }

    diagonal1Full := true
    diagonal2Full := true
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
       diagonal1Full = diagonal1Full && b.fields[i][i] == player
       diagonal2Full = diagonal2Full && b.fields[i][2-i] == player
    }

    if (diagonal1Full ||diagonal2Full) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

You can run it in the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cdR5t7SKUjT).

#### The problem

Since the last function in the snippet is declared as `func tryField(b board, field [2]int, result chan *board)` I assume the board `b` to be an indipendent copy, each time I call the method, because it's call by value. So changing this board should not affect the other boards in the other goroutines. But unfortunately **changing the board in one goroutine does affect the boards in the other goroutines** as the output of the programm is the following:

> input board:
> OO.
> ...
> ...
>
> result:
> OO.
> ...
> ...
> add O to field:  [1 0]
>
> OO.
> O..
> ...
> add O to field:  [2 1]
>
> OO.
> O..
> .O.

As you can see the initial field has two O's at the first and the second col in the first line. Adding an O to the position [1 0] works like expected, but when adding an O to the field [2 1] the there is also an O at [1 0], which was added in the previous goroutine and shouldn't be there since it's call by value.

---

#### The question

Why does the code in my snippet behave like it's **call by reference** although the function doesn't use a pointer?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where arrays are probably better suited than slices.

Comment: @Adino has your answer; I just want to give you a few references from the Go docs. I recommend reading through them. A blog post on slices: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro  The spec on slice types (other sections also cover slice usage): https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types  And pass-by-value: https://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value with maps and slices.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices are references to arrays. When modifying a slice without copying it, the underlaying array will be modified. Therefore, all slices that point to the same underlaying array will see this change.